# sdiff: how to see the full line?

Tags: sdiff

Simple sdiff

```
sdiff -s file1 file2withlonglines

db2disable_soap_udf             #                             | db2disable_soap_udf             #disable web server consum
                                                              > db2disable_soap_udf -n          #db name
                                                              > db2disable_soap_udf -p          #password
                                                              > db2disable_soap_udf -u          #user
```

As you can see the "disable web server.." is truncated, how to see the full line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-w` option to set the width.
Default is set as 130 columns per line.
[sdiff - man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sdiff)

> -w NUM --width=NUM
> Output at most NUM (default 130) columns per line.

For example

```
sdiff -s -w 200 file1 file2withlonglines
```